# Генератор СЛАУ помогите найти

Tags: математика, big-data

Для лабораторной работы требуется протестировать программу на больших данных. СЛАУ 100 размерность и даже 1000. Вопрос где взять такие готовые СЛАУ или мб в математических пакетах есть функции их генерации? Я не нашел. Подскажите мне пожалуйста.

Comment: Я бы автоматически сгенирировал матрицы этих СЛАУ, так чтобы матрица A была невырожденной.

Comment: В первом приближении, просто задаёшь случайный вектор-решение `X` и единичную матрицу `E`. Затем аналогично методу Гаусса только в обратном порядке умножаешь строки на случайные числа отличные от нуля и складываешь их. Гарантированно получится СЛАУ с ровно одним решением. Возможно не оптимально, но 1000 не такое большое число, на ум ничего лучше не приходит, а алгоритм не сложнее Гаусса.

Comment: Хорошая идея! Спасибо.